# How do I make a value in an array, when selected randomly, trigger a php script or a font color change elsewhere in the page?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

Here is my code:

```php
$extras = array(
    "No guitar solo",
    "One verse guitar solo",
    "Two verse guitar solo",
    "Guitar/vocals trade bars for a solo",
    "One verse vocal improv",
    "Roll a fourth verse"
);

echo $extras[array_rand($extras, 1)];
```

If "Roll a fourth verse" is the randomly selected value in the output, I need it to run a couple of php echo commands later in the page... or at the very least change the font color for a line of text later in the page.

Comment: Same question already asked 7 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38701365/3933332

Comment: Use a variable instead `echo` and check later?

Comment: dont echo the re result of the rand, save it to a var, then check that string against your specific sting and do things, give it a go at least

Comment: I do not know how to do that stuff. I need someone to show me.

Comment: then post what you have tried and the outcome.

Comment: No. I posted the script & I have and asked how to do something. I do not know PHP that well and am barely scraping by getting this project done. If you can help me by showing me an example of what you are talking about, that would be great, but if not then there's nothing I can tell you because I don't understand what you are talking about when you say "save it to a var and check the string". I am sorry if I am not on the same level of understanding as the other people asking for help on this site. It is still no reason to be rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$extras = array(
    "No guitar solo",
    "One verse guitar solo",
    "Two verse guitar solo",
    "Guitar/vocals trade bars for a solo",
    "One verse vocal improv",
    "Roll a fourth verse"
);

$selected=$extras[array_rand($extras, 1)]; //assign the selected to a variable

if($selected=='Roll a fourth verse'){ //compare that variable to a string if it matches the string ...
//do XXXX
}//end match
```